# How Dataflow/Apache Beam yields its element to the next step

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, apache-beam, dataflow

Let's say I have following DoFn:

```
class ReadGCSFile(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        record_count = 0
        source_path = element["gcs_path"]
        with GcsIO().open(source_path) as file:
            # I cut off initialization of reader object for better visibility
            record_reader = reader.get_records(file)
            for record in record_reader:
                yield record
```

And this is second step in Dataflow streaming pipeline.

First step is to read PubSub message (JSON) containing key "path" with path to file stored in GCS bucket.
I also have next step which is DoFn doing some kind of validation.

Let's say that file I am reading has 100k rows.
It seems that this step is finished once all 100k rows are loaded, then it triggers next step - validation.

**Is this normal, expected Dataflow behavior?**

I thought that `ReadGCSFile` class will yield row by row, so next DoFn class will get row by row immediately, not once the entire file is loaded and finished.

If `ReadGCSFile` returns result once entire file is loaded - it seems to be bottleneck without any possibility to be parallelized.